# Finding a sum in nested list using a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, sum

I have a data structure similar to this

```
table = [
    ("marley", "5"),
    ("bob", "99"),
    ("another name", "3")
]
```

What I would like to do, to get the sum of the 2nd column (5 + 99 + 3) functionally like this:

```
total = sum(table, lambda tup : int(tup[1]))
```

That would be similar syntax to the python function `sorted`, but that's not how you would use python's `sum` function.

What's the pythonic/functional way to sum up the second column?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One approach is to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
total = sum(int(v) for name,v in table)
```

Answer (score 14):

reduce can help

```
from functools import reduce

total = reduce(lambda accumulator,element:accumulator+int(element[1]), table,0)
```

Comment: I expect this is using the `reduce` defined in `functools`.  I just added that import.

Comment: Thanks @StevenC.Howell for clarification! In 2014, the answer was in Python2 where reduce is the basic functions. Yes for Python3 `reduce ` must be imported

Comment: Please properly name your arguments, `x` and `y` are not any helpful. I quickly wanted to know which one is sum and which one is current. Your "answer" isn't any helpful on that.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use lambda the following should solve it:

```
total = sum(map(lambda x: int(x[1]), table))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(map(int,zip(*table)[-1]))
```

is one way to do it ... there are many options however

Comment: option1 - ```sum(map(int, map(operator.itemgetter(1), table)))```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get at the values in a dictionary:

```
total = sum(map(int, dict(table).values())
```

This may be a little obscure.

Comment: This answer works, but it creates a dictionary per row in the table. This isn't very memory efficient.

Comment: It creates just one dictionary using the table, and iterates over the values converting each one to an integer, and then sums them. For a big table it could be prohibitive. @PeterdeRivaz's answer using a generator is the most Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using indexing.

```
total=sum(items[1] for items in table)
```